# jsviews implementing jquery ui extended widgets

Tags: jsrender, jsviews

I am trying to implement a custom jquery ui widget in jsviews.

the widget i am looking for is

https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-jQuery-UI-Plugin-For-Simle-Tokenized-Autocomplete-Autocomplete-Multiselect/

This widget is an extended version to the jquery ui autocomplete. How can we use this in jsviews

Comment: Did you look at https://www.jsviews.com/#samples/tag-controls/jqui/autocomplete and the way it was implemented here https://www.jsviews.com/download/sample-tag-controls/jsviews-jqueryui-widgets.js? See this section: https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsviews.com/blob/gh-pages/download/sample-tag-controls/jsviews-jqueryui-widgets.js#L241

Comment: Thanks for the inputs Boris Moore, I was able to load that autocomplete widget with the Multiselect option. I have one more issue. How do we call the widget method when we select on the autocomplete. I want to call/trigger the widget select event.

Comment: See this topic: Accessing widget APIs: https://www.jsviews.com/#samples/tag-controls/jqui/api. Also the various samples using jQuery UI widgets should help to see patterns you can use. Not sure of your exact requirements/scenario.... https://www.jsviews.com/#samples/tag-controls/jqui